# Texture size for different screen size in libgdx-Android Games

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I am creating my 1st Libgdx based game for android devices. I am worried if I need to create lot of images for different screen sizes. For now my game is so good in 800x400, when it is scaled to different size, the logic I have written based on the image size fails a lot.

Questions:
1. Is there is any way to get one big image and use it on as many devices we want. Something like we have high resolution image in drawable-hdpi  and scale down as it is needed in other devices.
2. I am trying to position the images based on the screen size and the size of the image. It is having problem when it comes to different size. Any better way to handle this ?

Kindly Advice.

Comment: I recommend using ExtendViewport to manage your camera so you can continue using the same 800x400 size you want. So you would instantiate ExtendViewport with 800x400, and then update it in the resize method with the actual screen dimensions. However, you will have to account for the screen extending either wider or taller than those dimensions. If you want to be lazy and just have black bars instead, use FitViewport instead.

Comment: how to pass the actual size to resize()

Comment: Create your viewport with `new ExtendViewport(800, 400);` to give it your desired virtual dimensions. The method `resize(int width, int height)` is called on your Game or Screen. Inside the `resize` method, you should call `viewport.update(width, height);`. Read the documentation:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Viewport works but the textures which was good is not in 400x800 is not good (pixalated) in bigger devices like 1080x1920. Anything i have take care